# How can I toggle between indent using spaces and tabs in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext

I'm happy with the indentation defaults, but sometimes I want to paste text that preserves the tabs and I don't want to grab the mouse, go to the lower corner, uncheck `Indent Using Spaces`, paste the text, and check `Indent Using Spaces` again.

Is there a way to do this from the command menu (`cmd+shift+p`) or by using an extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about defining a keyboard shortcut to toggle the `translate_tabs_to_spaces` setting?

Untested, but the stock keyboard binding file has this, which you copy and modify to your preferences in `Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`:

```
{"keys": ["f7"], "command": "toggle_setting", "args": {"setting": "translate_tabs_to_spaces"} },
```

Comment: so simple, thanks! edit your answer to have `f7` and `translate_tabs_to_spaces` so it doesn't use `spell_check` and I'll accept it

Comment: Edited, I just can't help striving for those internet points!